# Form validation with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a form, to make sure that the user inputs a value into a textbox. Here's my Javascript:

```
var formValidation = function(a) {
    if (document.getElementById(a).value == "") {
        alert('Please fill out the ' + a + ' field');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here's the form:

```
<div id="cultdiv">
    <form action="add.php" method="POST">
        <span><input type="hidden" name="id" id="cultid"/>
        <input type="text" onSubmit ="formValidation('culture')" name="name" id="culture"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="culture" />
        <input type="submit" value="add/update" /></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

For some reason it doesn't stop the form from being submitted or give the alert message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to `return` from your inline handler.
Also, `<input>`s don't have an `onsubmit` event; you probably meant to put that in the `<form>`.

Comment: inline handler? What does that mean?

Comment: By `return`ing a value, like any other `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

slaks means something along these lines.

```
<script>
var formValidation = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('culture').value == "") {
        alert('Please fill out the culture field');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
<div id="cultdiv">
    <form action="add.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return formValidation(this)">
        <span><input type="hidden" name="id" id="cultid"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="culture"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="culture" />
        <input type="submit" value="add/update" /></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you can look and learn by example how thing are done, a couple of sites eg javascriptkit.com, dynamicdrive.com